# Change the info iTunes displays for a song

Tags: itunes

The majority of the songs I have are individually purchased or downloaded songs, not complete albums.

In the categories "Recently Added" and "Downloaded" iTunes shows under the album artwork the name of the album and the artist. It would be much more helpful, if the name of the song and the artist would be shown.

I cannot find a preference setting for changing this. Is there a way to change the info which is displayed by iTunes?

The iTunes version is 12.9.2.5

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your question fully or strictly within the bounds of you asking it, but I have a workaround that can at least give you what you want in some fashion: smart playlists.

Create a smart playlist (File -> New -> Smart Playlist…) with these settings:

[image: smart playlist settings]

Tweak the time period and number of items to taste.

A smart playlist defaults to Playlist view…

[image: playlist view]

Switch to Songs view: highlight the new playlist, View -> View As… -> Songs.

[image]

(note: I took this screenshot with 25 items, not 9999)

…and finally tweak your columns to your liking by right-clicking and choosing your info:

[image]

You'll need to sort by Date Added (click the Date Added column to toggle sorting by ascending and descending) after all this to ensure you mimic the Recently Added feature in Library.

It's close, but not an exact match for what you want. The View -> View As… approach is not currently available for the Recently Added option in Library.

Comment: This is a very cool workaround. Thank you so much for elaborate and detailed answer!

Comment: No worries! I haven't looked into the Downloading side of your question, but I suspect you could combine two conditions in the smart playlist and have the first to check for if a file was downloaded…if that doesn't exist, there may be a way to check for 'Purchased AAC' or similar thing that typically denotes iTunes Store purchases. To be frank, I haven't bought anything from there in a long time, so I'm a bit rusty on that.